# OCI: Estimate cost given a list of instances

Tags: typescript, sdk, cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to estimate the cost of a list of instances from OCI using the TypeScript SDK. They have a tool [Cloud Cost Estimator](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/costestimator.html) where you make your configs and it shows the estimation dynamically. I want to do that through API. So I would send a request:

```js
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "compute.standard.x86",
            "shape": "VM.Standard2.1",
            "region": "us-ashburn-1",
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "storage.standard",
            "region": "us-ashburn-1",
            "quantity": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

And get a response:

```js
{
    "prices": [
        {
            "name": "compute.standard.x86",
            "shape": "VM.Standard2.1",
            "region": "us-ashburn-1",
            "quantity": 2,
            "price": {
                "amount": 0.048,
                "currency": "USD",
                "unit": "HOUR"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "storage.standard",
            "region": "us-ashburn-1",
            "quantity": 100,
            "price": {
                "amount": 0.08,
                "currency": "USD",
                "unit": "GB"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any module I could use to do that? Is it possible? I read the docs and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The cost estimator tool doesn't have a public API to interact with.

However, you can try using the list price API that is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/GSG/Tasks/signingup_topic-Estimating_Costs.htm#accessing_list_pricing